# python exporting csv file from sqlite database the values which has capital " L" are truncated

Tags: python, sqlite

```
 import sqlite3
 import pandas as pd


f = open('output.csv', 'w')

connection = sqlite3.connect('storage.sqlite')
cursor = connection.cursor()
cursor.execute('select * from product')

while True:
      df = pd.DataFrame(cursor.fetchmany(1000))
      if len(df) == 0:
         break

     else:
          df.to_csv(f, header=False)

     f.close()
     cursor.close()
     connection.close()
```

[image]

here the data was "Long Lad as" so while importing i got "ong ad as " in different cells of csv.

small "l" are not effected but capital L are being removed while exporting.

please help to fix this bug

Comment: first: use `print()` to see what get from database (before you create `df`), second: use `print()` to see what you have in `df`, third: `csv` is normal text file so open in normal editor to see what you have in file. maybe it truncate in different place.

Comment: see your image - you have some `L` as `Other ` so you remove `L` when you import file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See your image - you have set `L` as `Other` separator - so you remove `L` when you import file.

`CSV` is normal text file so you can open in normal editor and see if you have this `L` in text.